# Scifi book with FTL travel that caused the ship to split into multiple copies

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship

I'm trying to remember the name/series of this book that I read (at least) a few years ago.

It had a sci-fi space travel theme, but was mostly set on this planet that had "zones" that kept people separated by making them ill/or causing pain.

From what I remember they traveled using some sort of FTL system that caused the ship to split into multiple copies of itself, and one of the captains told the computer to destroy all the other copies of the ship. The ship(s) also traveled through time for some reason, and ended up at the planet (I think like 1,000+) years before they were supposed to.

I believe they were trying to prepare the planet for habitation before the main ship arrived carrying refuges or a main landing party.

Hope this is enough to trigger someone's recollection, as I have been looking for this book for a while now because I'm sure it was only the first in a series...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was it the Pathfinder series by Orson Scott Card?

It is not the main story line, but the main characters discover that a ship, attempting to jump to hyperspeed, duplicated into 19 others and traveled some random number of years into the past. One of the captains ordered that all the duplicates be killed by humanoid robots called "expendables".  They then founded 19 " wallfolds" to keep duplicate people from meeting each other.

["Pathfinder (Paperback)"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416991794), *Amazon*

The second book is called Ruins, I am not sure if there is a third out yet.

Comment: Awesome!  I've been trying to remember the name of that book for at least a couple of years now! I am pretty sure that is it, I will have to go digging through the books in my storage locker now just to find it to make sure.  I also see he just released the Third book called: Visitors in Nov '14.